# Silent install without extra features

Tags: windows-7, installation, automation, unattended, silent-install

I want to make for myself list of programs to make them be installed without any people near them. I found out info about silent/unattended installation, BUT it is installing programs with all default settings!! For example, Skype, propose me to make Bing default search engine, but I don't want it to be my default search engine. Other programs also often propose to download and install some extra programs. How can I solve this problem? Is there any other choices except AutoIt/VBScript or any other? How can I uncheck that default choices not showing to the user program's UI?

I found software http://ninite.com/
And it says:

"No Toolbars
Ninite automatically says "No" to toolbars and other junk." How can I do the same things? How to say NO to all junk from my point of view?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninite is not technically performing a traditional 'silent' install. As per the [How Ninite Works](http://ninite.com/help/how-ninite-works/) page:

> After downloading an app's installer and confirming its validity Ninite begins to install it. The specifics of this differ for each app but **our most general technique is to hide the installer's window when we run it and then automate the proper clicks and input to install the app right**. Ninite's automation says "No" to any toolbars or other junk just like if you asked a technical friend to install an app for you. Settings like installation location are left as their defaults.
>
> And that's how Ninite installs an app.

To replicate this process you can cook up custom AutoIt/AutoHotkey scripts that can similarly select the options and click the buttons you want for each installer. Of course, no doubt you'd need to run each installer multiple times to perfect your script, and each script would entail a lot of effort. Really, why bother when the Ninite folk have already done all the hard work for you? Just use it and save yourself precious time and energy.

Another option could be to extract each installer, then repackage it and create your own custom installer that does exactly what you want. Besides the possible legal issues involved (although perhaps it doesn't matter if you don't redistribute), this method will most likely require *even more* effort than the scripting solution.

Comment: Thanks. But what confuses me that for AutoIt I need to give a name of the window to capture it. But how to be if today I have RUS lang pack on my machine and window has name: "Установка скайп", and tomorrow I have ENG lang pack, and the window name will be: "Installing skype"? How can I handle that with AutoIt? Will I have to have several different files with localization strings for such cases? And what will be if Skype will release new version and change  windows captions?

Comment: And if they are using AutoIt - how do they do it "silently" without showing ANY user interface??

Comment: I never said *they* are using AutoIt or any freely available program. AFAIK app windows can be hidden and still be interacted with programmatically. As for proper window identification, AutoIt/AHK can also detect on the basis of internal class names and so on, which should be language independent I guess (you'll have to check). If a new installer is released with entirely different options/buttons, what makes you think the Ninite guys don't have to redo their scripts?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.ninite.com

> **No Clicking Next, Next, Next**
>
> Ninite fully automates installers offscreen.
>
> **No Toolbars**
>
> Ninite automatically says "No" to toolbars and other junk.
>
> **Always Up-to-date**
>
> A Ninite installer always gets an app's latest version no matter when you made it.
>
> **It Updates Too**
>
> Just run your Ninite installer again and it will update the apps to their latest versions.
>
> **No Signup**
>
> Ninite just works. No account, signup, or client needed.
>
> **32 and 64-bit**
>
> Ninite installs the best version of an app for your PC.
>
> **International**
>
> Ninite installs apps in your PC's language.
>
> **Faster for Business**
>
> Ninite Pro is 3x faster and allows business use.
>
> **Works with RMMs**
>
> Kaseya, Labtech, Level Platforms, KACE, GFI, Naverisk, and more. Ninite Pro integrates with everything.
>
> **Offline Mode**
>
> With offline support, a /silent switch, and desktop icon control Ninite Pro is even more flexible.
>
> **Security Made Easy**
>
> The /updateonly switch for Ninite Pro makes keeping software up to date simple.

Comment: Thanks, but if you read my question - I found that software too!!! I want to know how they do it internally! I want to make the same thing for me, but with my list of programs I like and use for my work!!!

Comment: @yozhik Yup, I saw that.  You edited it while I was answering.

Comment: Do you know how to do that internally or somehow?

Comment: @yozhik You'll probably never find out without looking at each program you want to install.  If they let everyone know, why would people continue to use them?

Comment: @yozhik For example, here is all of the Skype switches you're looking for: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Unattended-install/m-p/184740#M18609

Comment: Yes, I know that, but still there are no ways to uncheck Bing((

Comment: "no way to uncheck ***" yep that is the sad sad world we live in and it will only get worse and worse and worse. my 2 cents: switch to a Linux distro and thats it. lol. screw windows